# Codeigniter 4 ResourceController - minify json output

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-4

I'm using Codeigniter's Resource Controller to output some date from my API.

For example:

```
$data = ['id' => 8, 'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 27];
return $this->respond($data, 200);
```

Is there a way to minify the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to minify json response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487195/how-to-minify-json-response)

Comment: Kinda does, kinda doesn't. If I do it that way, the response is a string and codeignter sets the header to text/html. I think it will work. I was hoping for a codeigniter setting or some config value.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do :

```
$data = ['id' => 8, 'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 27];

   //add the header here
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $data );
```

Play with header type to get it right

> I was hoping for a codeigniter setting or some config value.

There is no such a thing, built in.

Answer (score 0):

You could play with HTTP Responses ([check example](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/outgoing/response.html#setting-the-output))

You could have something like this:

```php
$data = [
    'success' => true,
    'id'      => 123,
];

return $this->response->setJSON($data);
```

If you are using the [API Response Trait](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/outgoing/api_responses.html) you could check the `setResponseType()` function, for example:

```php
return $this->setResponseFormat('json')->respond(['error' => false]);
```